# How can I remove all transient objects from multiple photos, leaving only the background?

Tags: photoshop, image-manipulation, background

I have multiple images of (let's say) a busy street. All taken with the exact same angle, and the people are moving around.

It stands to reason that if I could compare all images and get only "the part that is common to all images", I would have an image of an empty street.

Any thoughts on how this could be achieved?

Comment: In Photoshop, use "Stack Mode" - see here:  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20953/how-do-i-remove-random-people-from-my-photos/20960#20960

Comment: There are a myriad of demonstrations of this on youtube.  Photoshop supports this effort through loading a stack, of images and automatically aligning them.

Answer (score 1):

you have two choices

the first method use software (photoshop)

1. shoot from the same angle using your tripod (preferable) - time laps shoots. or
2. shoot when you can see the street is clearer as much as possible some shoots.
3. now combine all your shoots in photoshop using Auto-align and median tool.

for more information please see that video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Ck62S7lrPA

The second method is to use your camera with a **long exposure** using your tripod and a suitable **ND filter** depending on how long you expose and the light intensity of your scene. some do it using a square glass holder with a dark glass.

for more please see that video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T24_uq0AY6o

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StarStaX](http://www.markus-enzweiler.de/software/software.html) to average the pictures if you want. It has a lot simpler interface than Photoshop (and is free!) for that kind of task.